# Table Multiple Sql Query Union

Tags: sql

I have following table which is having duplicate record with respect to different fields:

```
CREATE TABLE Student1
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;
    INSERT INTO Student1
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1,0,4500, 'ram', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,2000, 'shyam', '05/09/2013'),
    (4,0,1500, 'ghanshyam', '08/11/2014'),
    (3,0,4500, 'gopal', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,8000, 'radheshyam', '15/11/2013'),
    (4,1,1500, 'ghanshyam', '18/10/2015'),
    (1,1,4500, 'ram', '14/02/2012'),
    (2,0,6500, 'radhe', '11/11/2014'),
    (3,1,4500, 'gopal', '14/02/2015'),
    (5,1,4500, 'gopala', '04/02/2015'),
    (5,1,4500, 'gopala', '04/02/2015'),
    (6,0,14500, 'gopal', '14/02/2015')
;
```

I have 3 conditions to filter the table:

1. No complete duplicate record
2. If record with same `id` but different `Name` and `date` field then add all of them to final result
3. If `status=1` for any record then select that record of respective `id`
4. Add all record with `id` different from `id` of above 3 conditions

I have written this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Student1 
GROUP BY id,status,amount,Name,date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1  Student1
WHERE id IN
(
SELECT id FROM Student1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
AND COUNT(DISTINCT date) > 1
)

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1  Student1
WHERE status=1 AND id IN
(
SELECT id FROM Student1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2
);
```

Result:

```
id  status  amount  Name    date
4   1   1500    ghanshyam   18/10/2015
1   1   4500    ram 14/02/2012
3   1   4500    gopal   14/02/2015
5   1   4500    gopala  04/02/2015
2   0   2000    shyam   05/09/2013
2   0   8000    radheshyam  15/11/2013
2   0   6500    radhe   11/11/2014
```

As you can see 1st Select avoid duplicate, 2nd Select record with same `id` having different `Name`, `date`, 3rd Select to get record with `id=1`. I am using `UNION` to avoid duplication in result.

Now I need to add 4th query to get the record `id=6` which is not present in all the above condition.

Expected Result:

```
id  status  amount  Name    date
4   1   1500    ghanshyam   18/10/2015
1   1   4500    ram 14/02/2012
3   1   4500    gopal   14/02/2015
5   1   4500    gopala  04/02/2015
2   0   2000    shyam   05/09/2013
2   0   8000    radheshyam  15/11/2013
2   0   6500    radhe   11/11/2014
6   0   14500   gopal   14/02/2015
```

I need to solve the 4th query. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the only condition you want to filter, is `id = 6`, it is enough to add just:

```
SELECT * FROM Student1 WHERE id=6;
```

Which is direct translation of your request into SQL. And full version will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Student1 
  GROUP BY id,status,amount,Name,date
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1  Student1
  WHERE id IN
  (
  SELECT id FROM Student1
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT date) > 1
  )

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1  Student1
  WHERE status=1 AND id IN
  (
  SELECT id FROM Student1
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2
  )

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1 WHERE id=6;
```

Result is as requested but in different order. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37fd9/36/0)

However, if you would like to get all `id` which were not filtered with your coditions, but you don't know their values, I would use a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW Student2 AS 
  SELECT * FROM Student1 
  GROUP BY id,status,amount,Name,date
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1  Student1
  WHERE id IN
  (
  SELECT id FROM Student1
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT date) > 1
  )

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1  Student1
  WHERE status=1 AND id IN
  (
  SELECT id FROM Student1
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2
);

And then query with it:

SELECT * FROM Student2

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Student1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Student2);
```

The result is the same. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0ba8/1/0)

Comment: I want to redesign my 3rd Query Condition if there will be two record with status=1 then it should select record with lowest amount field

Comment: @LalitJadiya lowest in comparison to what? there are meny records with status=1, did you mean, the duplicate records with status=1, or one from all of records with status=1?